# ROS application using Qt5 qml

Tags: ros, qt5, qtcreator, cmake, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am developing a ground station application for a mobile robot. I usually create the qt-ros package using catkin_create_qt_pkg. I recently updated to qtcreator 5.0.2 and qtquick 2. Since I want to use QML UI for the interface and c++ for the logic part. I changed my cmake to be able to use QT5. However i still get errors whenever I use any qtquick 2 library.

For example when I try to use qquickview to define a view:

QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();

I get this error:  error: undefined reference to `QQuickView::QQuickView(QWindow*)'

My question is how can solve this ?
And is it possible to use qt5/qml with cmake to develope GUI's for ROS applications.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192843/ros-application-using-qt5-qml/) by [AmiraJr](https://answers.ros.org/users/19987/amirajr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if you have already found a solution to your question, but...

I'm not using Qt5, I'm using Qt4, but given that your error is an undefined reference, it means the linker cannot find the QtQuick library.

As far as I can tell, for Qt5 and QtQuick 2, the required components/modules are QtQml and QtQuick.

Would that be the issue?

I hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0